# Node texturing in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, node-editor

Hello fellow internet people,

I am currently trying to recreate the minecraft assets in blender, but I am encountering a problem as some of the textures files come as grayscale and have a colormap with the color data. Since I don't know how to setup the nodes, I am hoping someone could help me figure it out.

I have included the two png images in this post. Since the first one is 16x16, the interpolation has to be set to closest.

(sry for the terrible image formating)

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add the color to you texture, you need to combine the saturation and hue of the color texture, with the value of the grayscale. To do that you need a separate HSV and a combine HSV node as below.

[image: Simple node setup]

For the color the simpler is to just take one color from the texture with the color picker. However if you need the color variation, you can use a mapping node with a small scale factor and change the x and y position. Technically the result will not be perfect tho.

[image]